# How to set Weights and Gradient Weights in a layer of non-Sequential() Keras model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I have some pre-trained weights (both for layer and gradient) as Numpy Arrays, and I need to set them in a network I recreated.

Example of part of my network:

```
X_input = Input((4,256,256))
# batchSize is 4
# size so far: (batchSize,4,256,256)

X = Conv2D(96,(11,11), strides=(4,4), data_format = 'channels_first')(X_input)

# output of the convolution has size: (batchSize, 96, 62, 62)

X = BatchNormalization(axis = 1)(X) 
X = Activation('relu')(X)
X = MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2), data_format='channels_first')(X)
```

The np.array of weights I should set in the Conv2D layer has shape: **`(96, 4, 11, 11)`**

I can actually call the set_weights() function as with a Sequential() model like:

```
model.get_layer('layerName').set_weights(myNpArrayWeights)
```

But if I do so, this gives the error:

```
ValueError: You called `set_weights(weights)` on layer "step2_conv1" with a  
weight list of length 96, but the layer was expecting 2 weights. 
Provided weights: [[[[ 3.87499551e-03  1.32818555e-03  2.97062146e-0...
```

as if shape were incorrect?

So I tried to input 2 testing weights using `np.array([1,2])`.
This is the error reported:

```
ValueError: Fetch argument <tf.Variable 'step2_conv1_4/kernel:0' 
shape=(11, 11, 4, 96) dtype=float32_ref> cannot be interpreted as a Tensor. 
(Tensor Tensor("step2_conv1_4/kernel:0", shape=(11, 11, 4, 96), dtype=float32_ref)
is not an element of this graph.)
```

How do I solve this?

How do can I set the weights also for the gradient?

Python version: 3.6.5
Keras version: 2.2.4
Tensorflow version: 1.13.1

## EDIT

**For the first ValueError:**

In Conv2D layer set `use_bias=False` so that it expects only 1 array of weights, if use_bias is set True then an additional array of weights will be considered in the layer.

**For the second ValueError:**

Before instantiating the model, it is necessary to clear the session, because you might have run multiple times a model (as I did) and apparently Tensorflow gets confused about the multiple graphs present.

To clean the session run:

```
keras.backend.clear_session()
```

Comment: Which layer are you trying to set weights to? And what do you mean weights also for gradient?

Comment: I'm trying to add weights to the Conv2D layer at the moment.
I also have a np.array for gradient's weights that is different from the layer's weights.

Comment: Still I don't get what you call gradient weights

Comment: Let me clarify better, the weights I have come from a model trained on Torch7, from this I can see, apart from kernel size, stride and other things, 2 names: 'weight' and 'gradWeight', and both are Numpy arrays. I assume they are weights of the layer and of the gradient, but now I'm thinking one of those could a weighting mask of the other since I noticed they have the same shape. But anyway, the first problem remains...

Comment: Well the thing is that Keras does have any concept of "gradient weights". Your first issue is that you need to have an array with the convolutional filters AND the biases for each neuron/filter, and it seems you only have the filter weights.

Comment: I'm confused because the array shape is `(96, 4, 11, 11)`.
Even if I set `use_bias = False` the error remains. 
I also tried  `model.get_layer('layerName').get_weigths()` but it gives the same _second_ ValueError I posted above.

Comment: Ok, then start by making a self-contained example that reproduces the error, including model building and everything

Comment: Ok, so apparently what was firing the second ValueError was that my session was dirty. So running `keras.backend.clear_session()` before instantiating the model can solve this problem.